# Can D-Bus connect to a particular PID when there is more than one instance of a program running?

Tags: dbus

I'm trying to write a program which will interact with VLC over D-Bus.

When an instance of VLC is running I can execute things like this in the shell

```
qdbus org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Pause
qdbus org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Play
```

VLC pauses and resumes as expected. Great.

What if there is more than one instance of VLC running, how do I choose which instance the command is sent to? I know its PID. The DBus client doesn't have to be qdebus.

Answer (score 0):

no

every d-bus connection gets unique name and you can ask for other name later using `org.freedesktop.DBus.RequestName` call, but it has to be unique as well. See "[message bus names](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#message-bus-names)" part of spec. Note that one process can create multiple connections to bus (and thus have multiple names associated with it)

When you make a d-bus function call you use service name, object path, interface name and method name. First one is used by bus daemon to route your message, and service itself decides how to interpret path/interface/method/parameters part of message.

You can get pid the other way: well behaving dbus clients have to support `org.freedesktop.DBus` interface and you have `org.freedesktop.DBus.GetConnectionUnixProcessID`. You could iterate over all connections ( `ListNames` method ) and compare connection pid with what you have. This does not guarantee one to one mapping.